# How can I check on an SSHOperator with nohup to see if the job is done to complete the dag?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I created a dag that runs a python script on an ec2 instance. The python script takes about 2-3 hours to complete, so I added a nohup command to the SSHOperator. How can I check on interval to see if the ec2 python script job is done? I have thought about updating an environment variable and if the variable doesn't get updated in 3 hours the dag errors out. No sure how do I go about doing it and if there is a specific operator I could use to achieve this task. Alternatively any other best practice advice is dearly appreciated.

```
t2 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='ec2_worker',
    task_id='execute_script',
    command='nohup python me_script.py &',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: IIUC, why not just remove `nohup` and let the python script run? You can add `timeout` to the task if it takes too long.

Comment: For any reason if the sshconnection disconnects the script will stop too. I want to be able to allow the script to run during that time that's why I'm using nohup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the script write a success file to some known location when it finishes and then let the [SFTPSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/sensors/sftp_sensor/index.html) check for it.

Comment: If it's a daily job how can you distinguish yesterdays run vs. todays? The only thing I can think of is write the success file with date inside of it.

Comment: @codeBarer I would put a timestamp in the filename and then use `{{ ds }}` to construct the filename for which the sensor should look.